# Пример перекрытия методов в с++

Tags: c++

По заданию требуется привести пример использования перекрываемых методов(показать на примере , когда вызывается перекрываемый метод , а когда наследуемый). Как я понимаю , разница между переопределением и перекрытием методов в том , чтов в 1-ом случае в классе-потомке сам метод изменен , а во 2-ом используется его полная копия ? Если да , то как показать это на примере?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#pragma once
class MainTest
{
public:

    void method1()
    {
        cout << "method1" << endl;
    }
};
class Potomok:public MainTest
{
    void method1()
    {
        cout << "method1*" << endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Potomok v;
    v.method1();
    v.Potomok::method1();
    v.MainTest::method1();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
method1*
method1*
method1
```

Дополнено:

```
v.method1();
v.Potomok::method1();
```

По сути это одно и тоже, только в второй строке мы явно указываем метод какого класса вызываем.

Данный синтаксис можно использовать даже когда нет какой-то неопределенности

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class MainTest
{
public:
    void method1()
    {
        cout << "method1" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MainTest v;
    v.MainTest::method1();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Когда я прописываю первые две строчки , то компилятор ругается "функция potomok::method недоступно"

Comment: и можете объяснить, что происходит в следующих двух строчках?

Comment: ``компилятор ругается "функция potomok::method недоступно"`` Нужно добавить public: перед определением метода в классе Potomok